# In what way was the test of לֶךְ־לְךָ֛ greater than the test of א֣וּר כַּשְׂדִּ֗ים?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, abraham, parashat-lech-lecha

I assume that Avrohom's tests increased in difficulty.

The first test was whether or not to go into the furnace.

The test of leaving his birthplace has to be more difficult.

HKB”H made three promises that Avrohom would not lose out by leaving (Rashi - children,  money and fame).

In what way, therefore was the test of לֶךְ־לְךָ֛ greater than the test of א֣וּר כַּשְׂדִּ֗ים?

Comment: Note that according to Rambam (Commentary to Avot 5:3) Lech Lecha *was* the first test.

Comment: We all probably overlook the fact that Brit Beyn Habtarim preceded Lech Lechah by 5 years. So Avrohom was promised to return to this land and the "commandment" Lech Lechah was just a Go signal - he was already prepared for 5 years. This amplifies the question - was it a test at all!

Comment: What do you base your starting assumption on?

Comment: @AlBerko I thought it was a logical assumption. If AO passes test 1 which is more difficult than test 2, then test 2 was not really needed to establish anything about AO himself (although I admit it could have had other purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R. Yissocher Frand quotes two approaches [here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/ravfrand-5772-lechlecha/):

1. From R. Ya'akov Weinberg:

> Ur Kasdim was something Avram did out of his own convictions; it was not a response to a Divine Command. Lech Lecha — leaving his home — was a Divine Command and hence the fact that Avram obeyed this Command was of greater significance than the fact that he was prepared to act under his own convictions. In the eyes of the Torah, obeying the Master of the Universe is really the greatest test.

2. From R. Simcha Zissel Broide:

> [P]eople face two types of tests in their lifetimes. One type is those things that may be categorized as “glamorous tests” — defining moments in a person’s lifetime. At such times, when a person is well aware that he is at a junction in his lifetime when he must make a crucial decision — even one involving great self-sacrifice — he may be able to muster the courage and determination to make the proper decision.
>
> However, there are other tests in life — the daily type of challenges that come our way, day in, day out — that each and every one of us face. These tests are not glamorous. They are not exciting. They are very run of the mill, but they are challenges nonetheless.
>
> The test of “Ur Kasdim” was one of those glamorous defining-moment types of tests. The test of “Lech Lecha” is typical of the “daily grind” type of test. People sometimes have a capacity to rise above what they really are and to achieve spiritual levels above their normal capacities, but that is not who they really are ...
>
> [I]n the eyes of the Torah, the day in, day out, tests, represented by “Lech Lecha,” are what really count. Everyone can rise to the occasion occasionally. However, to do what you are supposed to do every day — day in, and day out — without questioning, this is a real test.

Comment: These just beg the question: how is sending away Hagar greater than Ur Kasdim? Neither was in response to a Divine command, and neither were particularly glamorous, yet the former came after the latter.

Comment: Which sending away of Hagar are you referring to? The one in Lech Lecha is not necessarily counted as a test, and the one in Vayera (with Yishma'el) was commanded by G-d.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain in what way they found this answer to be an "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"?

Comment: It's me, sorry. There's nothing wrong with you, nothing personal, I didn't like the answer and this general approach of citing contemporary Rabbis without Rabbinical sources. For me, Rabbis say a lot of educational and promotional Droshos without really meaning to address the problem. When they don't build a consistent view on the Sugya, it might be regarded as a Tirutz, but not too seriously.

Comment: @AlBerko Don't worry. I don't take it personally at all. And you're entitled to use your votes in any way that you see fit. I would, however, draw your attention to [this meta discussion](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/criterion-for-voting)